# Custom STL Allocator: Construct/Destroy called for each element

Tags: c++, allocator

I have this code snippet

```
auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

std::vector<char> myBuffer(20e6);

std::cout << "StandardAlloc Time:" << duration_cast<milliseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count() << std::endl;

start = high_resolution_clock::now();

std::vector<char, HeapAllocator<char>>myCustomBuffer(20e6);

std::cout << "CustomAlloc Time:" << duration_cast<milliseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count() << " CC: " <<  HeapAllocator<char>::constructCount << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
StandardAlloc Time:6
CustomAlloc Time:124 CC: 20000000
```

With this allocator

```
template<class T>
struct HeapAllocator
{
    typedef T value_type;

    HeapAllocator(){};

    template<class U>
    constexpr HeapAllocator(const HeapAllocator<U>&) noexcept {}

    [[nodiscard]] T* allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        auto p = new T[n];
        return p;
    }

    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n) noexcept
    {
        delete p;
    }

    template <class U>
    void destroy(U* p)
    {
        destroyCount++;
    }

    template< class U, class... Args >
    void construct(U* p, Args&&... args)
    {
        constructCount++;
    }
    static int destroyCount;
    static int constructCount;
};

template<class T>
int HeapAllocator<T>::constructCount = 0;
```

So it's obvious that construct/destroy are called for each char element of the buffer which results in 20x in execution time compared to default allocator. How can I prevent this behavior for this basic types?

Comment: The allocator is not responsible for calling the constructor; that's the job of `std::vector`. `new T[n]` does call the constructors though... E.g. `std::vector<MyType, MyAllocator> v; v.reserve(100); v.emplace_back(param);` should result in exactly 1 constructor call of a non-default constructor, but with your allocator implementation this would result in (at least) 100 calls to the default constructor.

Comment: Btw: You using `delete` instead of `delete[]` results in undefined behaviour. You shouldn't be calling any of the delete operators though since this would involve calling the destructor, which is also the responsibility of `std::vector`...

Answer (score 1):

You simply do not declare them at all. They will be defaulted through `std::allocator_traits` to use [`std::construct_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at)/[`std::destroy_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at) (i.e. a placement-new and (pseudo-)destructor call) instead, just as for `std::allocator`. This applies since C++11.

The functions are only taking so much time because you are modifying a static in them. Also, your implementations are not performing the job they need to do. `construct`, if you declare it, must construct an object of type `T` in the memory via a placement-new one way or another. And `destroy` must call the destructor, at least for types without trivial destructor.

That said, `std::vector<char> myBuffer(20e6);` and `std::vector<char, HeapAllocator<char>>myCustomBuffer(20e6);` will still take some time since they zero the allocated memory. `std::vector` doesn't offer any interface to leave it uninitialized and there is some dependence on the compiler recognizing that the `std::construct_at` loop can be optimized to a `memset`. (For `std::allocator` the standard library can simply specialize to `memset` directly when it sees `std::allocator` is used.)

However, `std::vector` offers `.reserve` instead which will reserve enough memory through `allocate` without constructing any objects in it. Objects can then be created with `push_back`/`emplace_back`/`resize` as required later.

---

Also your allocator has some other issues:

- `auto p = new T[n];` is wrong. `allocate` is supposed to allocate memory, not to construct objects. You should be only allocating memory of appropriate size and alignment, e.g. with `::operator new[](n*sizeof(T), std::align_val_t{alignof(T)})`, after an overflow check on the multiplication. Similarly `deallocate` should then use the matching deallocation function (e.g. `::operator delete[]`). That aside `delete` and `new[]` are a mismatch with undefined behavior as well. After `new[]` you *must* use `delete[]`, not `delete`.
- Your class lacks `operator==` (and `operator!=` before C++20). They are required and if your class doesn't have any non-static data members and doesn't define a `is_always_equal` member, then `operator==` must always return `true` and `operator!=` always `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I replaced new with malloc (C++14) and removed the static members as well as the implementations of construct and destruct. So all the allocator does is call malloc(size(T) * n) in allocate and free(p) in deallocate. It still takes almost 20x to construct the vector of the same size compared to using the default constructor

Comment: @tmanthey Cannot reproduce, see https://godbolt.org/z/TPjYa3nsP. MSVC has them at equal timing now. Clang optimizes both allocations away and GCC actually optimizes only the custom allocator away, making it faster (although that is probably because I am missing some checks and `throw`s in `allocate`). In fact looking at the timings I now suspect that you didn't enable optimizations for your benchmark at all, in which case the results would be completely meaningless.

Comment: I double checked and your assessment about optimization was unfortunately right. 
After turning on optimizations I get 6ms on the default allocator and 9ms on the HeapAllocator